# Right continuity of a function through sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that, for any non-increasing sub-sequence  $s_1,s_2,\dots$ going to $0$, i.e. ($\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0$) we have that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(s_n)=L$.

Does this imply   $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=L$?

Comment: Suppose not. Then there exists $\epsilon_{0} >0$ such that for all $\delta >0$, there exists $x$ such that $x \in (0, \delta)$, but $|f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon_{0} $. For $n \geq 1$, define $\delta_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$, we may choose $x_{n}$ with $x_{n} \in (0, \delta_{n})$ and $|f(x_{n}) - L| \geq \epsilon_{0}$, which contradicts the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does.
Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ does not converge to L. Then for some $\varepsilon > 0$, 
$$
\text{for all }\delta > 0 \text{ there is }0<x<\delta\text{ such that }\lvert f(x)-L\rvert \ge \varepsilon. \tag{*}
$$
Let $s_0$ be such that $0 < s_0 < 1$ and $\lvert f(s_0)-L\rvert \ge \varepsilon$. Given $(s_i)_{i\le n}$, let $s_{n+1}$ be as given by (*), such that $0 < s_{n+1}<\min(s_n, 2^{-n})$ and $\lvert f(s_{n+1}) - L\rvert\ge \varepsilon$.

Then $(s_n)$ is a nondecreasing sequence with $lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = 0$, but for all $n$, $\lvert f(s_n) - L\rvert \ge \varepsilon$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(s_n) \ne L$.